# MySQL Query not updating values in the database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an if/else block of code below that is supposed to call a function with specific parameters, depending on the situation. The function updates specific values in the MySQL database. However, the database values are not being updated. What am I doing wrong?

The following is my code:

**process.php**

```
$success = false;

$homeScore = $_POST['home'];
$awayScore = $_POST['away'];
$homeTeamName = $_POST['homeTeam'];
$awayTeamName = $_POST['awayTeam'];

try {
    $win = 0;
    $loss = 0;

    // HOME TEAM
    if ($homeScore > $awayScore)
    {
        $win = 1; $loss = 0;
        updateStandings($db7, $homeTeamName, $win, $loss);
        $win = 0; $loss = 1;
        updateStandings($db7, $awayTeamName, $win, $loss);
    }
    // AWAY TEAM
    elseif ($awayScore > $homeScore)
    {
        $win = 1; $loss = 0;
        updateStandings($db7, $awayTeamName, $win, $loss);
        $win = 0; $loss = 1;
        updateStandings($db7, $homeTeamName, $win, $loss);
    }

    $success = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $success="/error";
}
header("Location: " . $success);

function updateScore($db, $gameID, $home, $away)
{
    $db -> updateScoreForGame($gameID, $home, $away);
}
function updateStandings($db, $teamName, $win, $loss)
{
    $db -> updateLeagueStandings($teamName, $win, $loss);
}
```

**updateLeagueStandings function**

```
public function updateLeagueStandings($teamName, $win, $loss) {
    try {
        $sth = $this -> db -> prepare("UPDATE teams SET wins = wins + (:winsNum), losses = losses + (:lossesNum) WHERE Name = `:teamName`");
        $sth->bindParam(':winsNum', $win, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(':lossesNum', $loss, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(':teamName', $teamName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth -> execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header('Location: /error');
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? Is the query wrong? I ran the query with substituted values in PHPMyAdmin and it worked fine, so it can't be the query.

Comment: $homeTeamName > $awayTeamName --- isn't this their name. Shouldn't you be comparing the scores? $homeScore = $_POST['home'];
$awayScore = $_POST['away'];

Comment: I apologize, I mis-copied that part of the code here. The code I have already says: `if ($homeScore > $awayScore)...elseif ($awayScore > $homeScore)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE Name = `:teamName`
```

If this is what exactly in your script, then you need to remove the backtick quote around the variable.

The backticks are used to quote field names.

[some extend reading](/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)